# Valid equivalent partitions in a range from -100 to 100?

Tags: testing, partitioning, equivalence, manual-testing

I can't figure out this question.

A program which accepts an integer in the range -100 to +100:

**1)** How many valid equivalent partitions are there?

**2)** For which range what are minimum and maximum values?

**3)** Using `BVA`, what values need to be checked for the partitions?

So..., according to the equivalence testing, you can have a valid and invalid value. I supposed the invalid values would be anything less than -100 and greater than 100. However I can't find information about how to get equivalent partitions.

I mean, I can chose and say that it has 20 equivalent partitions, for example: -100 to -90 | -89 to 70 etc..., but: **Is there a way to get this?**

For the other questions: **Is it possible get the previous partition so the minimum value would be -100 and the maximum -90?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how basic EPA & BVA applies to your data

[image]

So, practically in your case you'll have 3 values from equivalence partitioning and 4 values from boundary values analysis.

- Don't forget to pay attention to 0. It's always a tricky point..

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For Boundary value analysis, the main focus should be for the corner cases.
So for the above range, values needed to be checked for BVA are:

-101  -100  100  101 (This is as per ISTQB)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is <-100;100> range so -100 and 100 are valid.

1) How many valid equivalent partitions are there?

Only one with any number from given range

2) For which range what are minimum and maximum values?

The minimum is -100 and the maximum is 100

3) Using BVA, what values need to be checked for the partitions?

Using BVA you have 6 values to be checked -101, - 100, -99, 99, 100 and 101 (the minumum/ the maximum and the next valid one just to find bugs in x>-100 except x>=-100, i.e. when programmer wrote x>-100 and you will check only -100 you will not find a bug, if you check also -99 you will find a bug).

Answer (score 0):

**1) How many valid equivalent partitions are there?**

Theoretically for your range of -100 and 100 there would be three equivalent class partitions:

1) one partition having values below -100 i.e. -101,-102 etc. These are invalid values class.

2) Second partition having values between -100 and 100(including -100 and 100). These are valid values class.

3) Third partition having values greater than 100 i.e. 101,102 etc. These are invalid values class.

Now you can choose one value from each partition. For example,

1) You can choose -118 from first class(invalid class partition).

2) You can choose 70 from second class(valid class partition).

3) You can choose 170 from third class(invalid class partition).

But in my view if you want to check with more values you can do more partitions within class -100 to 100. For example you can divide it into -100 to -51, -50 to 0, 1 to 50, 51 to 100. Then you can choose one value from each of these partitions.

*The main purpose of ECP is to reduce the number of test cases(test values) so if you have enough time then you can choose more than one value from each class or you can do make more classes and choose values from them.*

**2) For which range what are minimum and maximum values?**

1) For first class minimum value cannot be described, maximum value is -101.

2) For second class minimum value is -100 and maximum value is 100.

3) For Third class minimum value is 101 and maximum value cannot be described.

**3) Using BVA, what values need to be checked for the partitions?**

For BVA following values need to be checked:

1) Value immediately below minimum value i.e. -101.

2) Minimum value i.e. -100.

3) Value immediately above minimum value of range i.e. -99.

4) value immediately below than maximum value of range i.e. 99.

5) Maximum value of range i.e. 100.

6) Value immediately above maximum value of range i.e. 101.

Answer (score 0):

A program which accepts an integer in the range -100 to +100:

In Equivalance:
Test Scenario # Test Scenario Description   Expected Outcome

```
Class I: values < -100   => invalid class
Class II: -100 to +100   => valid class
Class III: values > +100  => invalid class
```

In BVA,

```
1) Test cases with test data exactly as the input boundaries of input domain i.e. values -100 and +100 in our case.

2) Test data with values just below the extreme edges of input domains i.e. values -101 and +99.

3) Test data with values just above the extreme edges of input domain i.e. values -99 and +101.
```